# Is there a default value to the Azure Active Directory token expiration timeout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, azure, session-timeout, azure-active-directory

This might be a noob question. I'm trying to detect session timeout. Now the default ASP.NET session timeout value is 20 minutes. However I have a site that leverages Azure AD for authentication. Is there a default value that the token expires at? Is this something that is configured or has a set value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see the post http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/03/20/azure-ad-token-lifetime/. Also adding useless text because of S.O. length validation

Comment: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/03/20/azure-ad-token-lifetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AAD access tokens expire in 1 hour.  AAD refresh tokens expire in about 14 days if they are not used. Each new refresh token starts the 14 day clock over again. This works for a total of 90 days. But after 90 days, the user will have to enter credentials again.

For ADFS the refresh token expiry is even shorter, something like 24 hours, unless the sign-in is from a registered device.

Answer (score 2):

Today the access token expires after 1 hour, but there is no guarantee that this will remain the same.

It cannot currently be configured.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD access tokens expire after one hour by default.